# Unable to process class AbstractTableViewer.class in JarAnalyzer File org.eclipse.jface-3.13.2-SDK-4.7.3.jar

Tags: maven, jface, maven-surefire-plugin

While running test using surefire test I see the following stack trace.

```
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
            [WARNING] Unable to process class org/eclipse/jface/viewers/AbstractTableViewer.class in JarAnalyzer File /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jface/org.eclipse.jface/3.13.2-SDK-4.7.3/org.eclipse.jface-3.13.2-SDK-4.7.3.jar
            org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
            at org.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:146)
            at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:67)
            at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:222)
            at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:136)
            at org.apache.maven.shared.jar.classes.JarClassesAnalysis.analyze(JarClassesAnalysis.java:92)
            at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.Dependencies.getJarDependencyDetails(Dependencies.java:259)
            at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.hasSealed(DependenciesRenderer.java:1517)
            at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.renderSectionDependencyFileDetails(DependenciesRenderer.java:535)
            at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.renderBody(DependenciesRenderer.java:258)
```

I have tried finding similar issues but none of them are related to org.eclipse.jface-3.13.2-SDK-4.7.3.jar. While rest of them are asking for updating jar versions I do not see anything for jface.

In general I am trying to find an explanation on why we see Unable to process class someclass.class in JarAnalyzer File somejar.jar error. Also, hoping to find a solution to this JFace problem.

Comment: Turns out that I was using a Jenkins plugin which was using an old bcel dependency. I had to add the following plugin to my plugins under build section on my POM. <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
         <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
         <version>6.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was using a Jenkins plugin which was using an old bcel dependency. I had to add the following plugin to my plugins under build section on my POM.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
                    <version>6.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                    <version>64.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```